# Mersenne with input

Tags: python

Can someone explain why I get the error message and/or what to do to fix it?

```
def mersenne(n):
    return (2**n-1)

print('Enter a number')
numberOne = input()
mersenne(numberOne)
print('Enter a number')
numberTwo = input()
mersenne(numberTwo)
print('Enter a number')
numberThree = input()
mersenne(numberThree)
print('Your Mersenne numbers are ' + numberOne + ', ' + numberTwo + ', ' + numberThree + '.')
```

The error message I get in IDLE is

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Please use the preview feature and use a code block to format your code a next time.

Comment: `input()` returns a string. You'll have to convert it to an integer or float before applying it to the `pow` (`**`) function. For example, `numberOne = int(input())`.

Comment: You can also put a (query) string in the `input()` function, e.g. `input("Enter a number: ")`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the input like this: `int(input("Enter a number: "))`

Comment: ok, that works, however, the formula is not being used in the end result.  can I bother you for some help one more time?

Answer (score 0):

Well you will have to convert your input from a string to an integer. You can do that by either:

```
numberOne = int(input())
```

Which automatically makes the input an integer or:

```
return (2**int(n)-1)
```

Which turns the input into the number while running the function. You can also use `float()` and with/or `raw_input()` as well. Just remember to change your inputs into integers or floats! I hope this helps you!

Without using the `int` in your function `return` line, you can use:

```
print('Your Mersenne numbers are ' + int(numberOne) + ', ' + int(numberTwo) + ', ' + int(numberThree) + '.')
```

Comment: ok, that works, however, the formula is not being used in the end result. can I bother you for some help one more time?

Answer (score 0):

Cast your input to `int` and assign the return value from `mersenne` to a variable:

```
def mersenne(n):
    return (2**n-1)

print('Enter a number')
numberOne = int(input())
mersenneOne = mersenne(numberOne)
print('Enter a number')
numberTwo = int(input())
mersenneTwo = mersenne(numberTwo)
print('Enter a number')
numberThree = int(input())
mersenneThree = mersenne(numberThree)
print('Your Mersenne numbers are ', mersenneOne, ', ', mersenneTwo, ', ', mersenneThree, '.', sep='')
```

You also can't concatenate an integer to a string with `+`. (This isn't JavaScript). The above works in Python 3 with the `print` function. If you're on Python 2, you can always cast back to `str`:

```
print('Your Mersenne numbers are ' + str(mersenneOne) + ', ' + str(mersenneTwo) + ', ' + str(mersenneThree) + '.')
```